# Android compilation from source

Tags: android, android-source

Im trying to compile android from source and followed the steps given in

1.http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

2.http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

3.http://source.android.com/source/building.html

Everything went fine until i tried to use "lunch full-eng" given in the 3rd link.The error i got was this.

[image]

Can somebody help me out with this problem?I have cloned the samsung.git from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Does samsung.git mean that you have downloaded kernel version for samsung phones `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/samsung.git`? If yes, then you cannot build this kernel for your emulator. Emulator requires goldfish kernel.

Comment: I cloned into goldfish but the shellscript envsetup.sh does not detect goldfish mainly cuz it does not have a vendorsetup.sh.any suggestions?

Comment: I do not understand what are you going to do. If you want simply build android sources then you do not need to copy kernel code because it is downloaded automatically with android. If you want to rebuild the kernel, then you at first have to build kernel and just then build android sources. So I propose you to download android sources without kernels and build them.

Comment: Sorry i am sort of a noob,How do i compile without the kernal.Can you please tell me a detailed procedure?

Comment: You should follow the instructions on http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html But you do not need to execute steps that are in the "Downloading kernels" section. After this simply build the code.

Comment: I did as you said.I deleted the downloaded kernels and ran 'lunch' command but still im getting the same error when i select full-eng option.Full-eng is for the emulator.

Comment: Can you download sources once again? I guess that you've not downloaded all of them.